# play audio from a stream in android

Tags: android

How to play audio from a stream in android???

I will get input stream  from an online link( like continuous FM).

I need to cache the stream and play it.

I searched a lot in sites,,,but didnt get.They show option of playing from a stored file.

There is no option to play from a stream.

Answer (score 2):

See if this tutorial helps:
[Custom Audio Streaming with Media player](http://www.google.com/url?url=http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/&rct=j&ei=IP9zS7nQGIuTkAXJmq2lCg&sa=X&oi=nshc&resnum=1&ct=result&cd=1&ved=0CAwQzgQoAA&q=pocket+journey+android+%2B+streaming+audiop&usg=AFQjCNEjP1LtehecivhXG-7NnLQkohReiw)

Comment: Link is no longer valid

Comment: Here's an alternative: https://www.ssaurel.com/blog/implement-audio-streaming-in-android-applications/